# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_zmq'

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

`import zmq` gives the error below.

I have installed pyzmq and everything. The zmq folder includes `_zmq.py`, so why is this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/upboard/visioonbot/Connect4Py/connect4.py", line 9, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "/home/upboard/visioonbot/Connect4Py/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _zmq import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_zmq'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

zmq dir:
[image]

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: which os, and how did you install? (https://pypi.org/project/pyzmq/)

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 , I tried pip install pyzmq. I also tried pip install ipython pyzmq tornado which I saw somewhere as a solution.

Comment: Share also your code.

Answer (score 0):

ensure you have python version 3 of zmq installed